# BLE connect to multiple devices (Swift)

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

How to connect BLE multiple devices at the same time in Swift

I'm working on iOS application project using BLE to transfer some data between them. The concept is one device is the main device that broadcast the data to other devices, then device that get data from bluetooth send data back to the main device.
How to connect multiple devices at the same time using core bluetooth? (1-to-many topology)
Is that possible to send and receive data in the same time?

Comment: Perhaps [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity) framework is what you want.

Comment: You can have multiple `CBCentralManager` instances in your app.

Comment: You generally should not generate multiple CBCentralManagers. One CBCentralManager can handle many peripherals.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different roles: peripheral and central.

> A peripheral typically has data that is needed by other devices. A central typically uses the information served up by a peripheral to accomplish some task.

The central can discover and connect to multiple peripherals.

See [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) for details. Even it is archived, it has the good overview of the feature.